# dplyr arrange() with ifelse conditional

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

Simple question, looking for a 'one-liner' -type answer, but can't quite find what I'm looking for in other similar questions.

Want to put an `ifelse()` conditional inside `dplyr::arrange()`. Simply put: if `x=1` then `arrange(df,N)` otherwise `arrange(df,desc(N))`. For completeness, x will only ever either be 1 or -1.

mwe:

`x=1; df = data.frame(N=c(-5:5))`

I figured `arrange(df, ifelse(x==1,N,desc(N)))` would work just fine but no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifelse` is vectorized and is for vectors. It always returns a vector of the same length as the input.

For more general usage, use `if(){} else{}`.

```
arrange(df, if(x == 1) N else desc(N))
```

Comment: Should we use the curly brackets like `arrange(df, if (x==1) {N} else {desc(N)})`  or not?

Comment: Curly braces are only strictly necessary for multiline expressions. (This is generally true, with `if` `else`, `for`, `function`...) With such short expressions in the result, I think this case reads clearly without the curly braces.

Comment: I see! It's funny I never thought the general `if(){} else{}` syntax worked inside function calls. Thanks